# PostgreSQL: concatenate nested arrays with differing element dimensions

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Concatenating the nested arrays `{{1,2}}` and `{{3,4}}` is no problem at all:

```
SELECT array_cat(
           ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2]]
         , ARRAY[ARRAY[3,4]]
       )

   array_cat   
---------------
 {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

But how to concatenate `{{1,2}}` and `{{3}}` in order to get `{{1,2},{3}}`?

```
SELECT array_cat(
           ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2]]
         , ARRAY[ARRAY[3]]
       )
psql: …: ERROR:  cannot concatenate incompatible arrays
DETAIL:  Arrays with differing element dimensions are not compatible
         for concatenation.
```

Comment: What structure do you expect for the final array? {{1,2},{3}} ?

Comment: I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible in PostgreSQL. Multi-dimensional arrays must have the same number of element dimensions, just as the error message informs. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)

> Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension. A mismatch causes an error.

You might want to pad with NULL or some other dummy value ...

Comment: I've already feared that. Seems like I have to look for another approach for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following method, instead of padding with NULL, for jagged arrays which extends from the original example:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(elem) FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(
    jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(v))
  ) AS elem
  FROM (
    VALUES 
    (ARRAY[1,2]), 
    (ARRAY[3])
  ) AS vals(v)
) q;
```